# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /register

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting this error even I am to render the template. I tried changing the function names also.

This is happening due to flask(error) I think

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in **call**
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/website/main.py", line 57, in register_user
    return render_template(url_for('main.register_form'))
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 138, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 60, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/Users/ayyagari/Documents/DeepNews/web_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /register

```
Here is my code 


from flask import (
    Blueprint, redirect, render_template, request, url_for,
    flash)

from website.db import get_db

bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)


@bp.route('/home')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@bp.route('/register')
def register_form():
    return render_template("form.html")


@bp.route('/success')
def success():
    return render_template("response.html")


@bp.route('/register_user', methods=["POST"])
def register_user():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email_id = request.form['reg-email']
        company = request.form['reg-company']
        type_of_business = request.form['industry_type']
        checkbox = request.form['reg-check']
        db = get_db()
        error = None
        if not email_id:
            error = 'Email ID is required.'
        elif not company:
            error = 'Company is required.'
        elif not type_of_business:
            error = 'Type of Business is required.'
        elif not checkbox:
            error = 'Accept the Terms and Conditions'
        elif db.execute(
                'SELECT id FROM beta_users WHERE email_id = ?', (email_id,)
        ).fetchone() is not None:
            error = 'User {} is already registered.'.format(email_id)

        if error is None:
            db.execute(
                'INSERT INTO beta_users (email_id, company, type_of_org, checkbox) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                (email_id, company, type_of_business, checkbox)
            )
            db.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('main.success'))

        flash(error)

    return render_template(url_for('main.register_form'))


@bp.route('/error')
def errors():
    return render_template("404.html")
```

API is also showing a 500 Internal server error

Comment: Please format your code, it is unreadable. Read this if you have doubts on how to format: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
return render_template(url_for('main.register_form'))
```

`url_for` returns a url to access the route via the Internet, which isn't what `render_template` uses. `render_template` is expecting a html/text file.

So, either replace that either with:

```
return render_template('register.html')
```

Or redirect the user to the other route, to let it do it's work:

```
from flask import redirect
...
return redirect(url_for('main.register'))
```

Comment: What if  I want to even flash my errors? Cause it is not working if I want to throw any error messages mentioned!

Comment: Flashed messages will stack up until a template processes the stack-- so as long as you flash the error just before the redirect-- you should have access to them in the /register routes template.